# How do I combine MIDI files?

Tags: midi

I'm trying to create a mash-up of two different songs, and I need to combine two different files to do so. I don't need them to play in sequence, but at the same time.

Comment: What kind of MIDI's are we talking about here? Plain MIDI files with note data or MIDI files that are formatted to Standard MIDI?

Comment: How do you play any single midi file normally? The answer very much depends on that.

Comment: You can add multiple midi tracks in virtually any multitrack recording application like pro tools, cubase, reaper etc - what are the exact issues you run into?